# If/and/if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, syntax

I had a quick question about performance in a javascript code. For example, say I had a function with a parameter and some if statements inside:

```
function myFunction(a,b,c) {
    if(condition) {
        //execute
    } else { 
        //execute
    }
}
```

In this particular case I need to compare multiple conditions in my if statement. Based on my understanding, there are two ways to do this:

```
function myFunction(a,b,c) {
    if(a === b && b === c) {
        //execute
    } else { 
        //execute
    }
}
```

or:

```
function myFunction(a,b,c) {
    if (a === b) {
      if (b === c) {
        //execute
    } else {
        //execute
    }
}
}
```

My question is, based on performance, which is better to use. Clarification: this question is **NOT** based on opinionated answers, it is strictly based on the question are there any possible issues that could arise using one or the other? For example, you don't *have* to declare a variable using the var keyword, but problems could arise (between global and local variables under the same name) if you don't. Could a problem similar to the variable example arise in any of these two if/and statements?

Comment: In programming there are multiple ways of doing things.

Comment: To check javascript performance, use http://jsperf.com/

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that unless you're actually evaluating something inside the conditionals (function call, etc) the performance difference will be negligible.  (as in, the time you spend thinking about this is longer than the time people would collectively save from having the page run faster over the lifetime of your code)

Comment: FYI- the logic between your two examples is not equal. When `a!==b`, the else clause wouldn't run in your second example as it would in the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your performance question is moot, as the different ways of writing the code gives different results.

With the second way of writing it, the `else` block is only executed when `a !== b`, but not when `a === b` and `b !== c`.

---

Ignoring the `else` part, you would get very similar performance with the difference codes, as they do the same thing. Performance will vary between browsers, and even between different versions of the same browser, so even if you find that one method is often faster in most of the current browsers, that could very well change in a near future.

Both methods works well, and doesn't have any nasty performance issues, so you should simply use the one that most clearly resembles the intention of the code.

Comment: + for recognizing the logical difference.

Comment: Yea I can't believe I didn't see that thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `console.time('name')` and `console.timeEnd('name')` to check performance in JS.

Made a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/bwYT7/

Comment: Yea I knew about console.time() but my question was based more on if different results would arise as was pointed out by @Guffa . Can't believe I missed that.